# How to add padding within React Modal?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm building my first React modal.  The basic structure is now done but I want to have more padding in between the border and the contents.  I thought this would be simple but I've tried several things and none work.

```
  return (
    <div className={classes.backDrop}>
      <Modal
        backdrop={'static'}
        size='lg'
        show={true}
        centered={true}
        style={classes.modalContainer}
        data-testid='addFleetCustomerModal'
      >
        <div className='modalContainer'>
          <ModalHeader>

          </ModalHeader>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Title>
              Add Customer
            </Modal.Title>            
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label className={classes.highlight}>Company Name*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control id='companyName' data-testid='companyName' type='text' placeholder='For example: ABC Corp.'

              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>
                <strong>NOTES</strong><br/>
                Notes added here can only be viewed and edited by other team members.
              </Form.Label>
              <textarea className="form-control" id="companyNotes" rows="3"></textarea>
            </Form.Group>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Row>
              <a href='/#'>Cancel</a>
              &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
              <Button variant='secondary' size='sm'>&nbsp; Next &nbsp;</Button>
            </Row>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
```

Any ideas on what CSS I should add (and where) to move the content of the modal inward a bit more?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: By content, you mean only stuff inside `<Modal.Body>` or the whole `<Modal>`?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
.modal-header,
.modal-body,
.modal-footer {
  padding: 2rem; //change the padding as you want
}
```

this will change the padding but the with full width lines between sections.

See [Working demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-carson-0qf56)

you can also add the padding around the whole modal but this this won't make the lines full width:

```
.modal-content {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

See [Working demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-rhodes-fczlo)

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, everyone.  I must have been really tired yesterday afternoon when I posted this.  Let me explain the solution:

The code I posted above is inside a functional component that is defined like this:
`const AddCustomer = ({ classes }) => {`

`classes` comes from the parent component, which is defined like this:
`class UserMgmtPage extends React.Component {`

In this parent component, the CSS styleSheet is injected into via `react-jss` code.  I then pass does these same CSS classes into functional child component.

You'll notice this 2nd line, which was always working:
`<div className={classes.backDrop}>`

My failure was to use the same syntax.  Thus the solution is this:
`<div className={classes.modalContainer}>`

Sorry for the trouble but I do appreciate everyone who tried to help!